# tkProgressBar for linux environment

Tags: r, linux, windows

I have build an application using `R language` in a **windows environment**. Inorder to show the percentage of the code progress i am using `tkProgressBar` like mentioned below:

```
pb <- tkProgressBar(title = "progress bar", min = 0,max = 100, width = 300) 
samp<-sample(5:10,1)
setTkProgressBar(pb, samp, title=paste( samp,"% done"))
```

Now i have deployed the same application in **linux environment**. As of now i am using shiny server to view the application. When ever i run the application i get the below error:

```
Warning: Error in structure: [tcl] invalid command name "toplevel".    
Stack trace (innermost first):    
71: structure    
70: .Tcl.objv    
69: tcl    
68: tkwidget    
67: tktoplevel    
66: tkProgressBar
```

Please advice on the same.